# Not able to build Q#/C# project in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, q#

I have written Q# code inside a C# project in VS Code. When I would click on **Debug -> Start Without Debugging** it would give a whole slew of build errors as shown in the images below.
Can someone please help me out with this

To run the vs code I have installed: .NET Core SDK 3.0 or later & VS Code extension
system: Mac osx 10.13.3 
[image: the code snippet]

[image: error upon clicking: start without debugging][image: error after clicking *debug anyway*]

Comment: Does this help https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/quantum/install-guide/?view=qsharp-preview ?

Comment: In my case, C# worked but Python didn't.

Comment: @gnoejh how did you manage to run the C# code?

Answer (score 0):

The errors in your screenshot are coming from a generated `.cs` file inside the `/obj` folder, indicating that duplicate assembly attributes are being found while attempting to build your project. Because the build fails, it cannot proceed to run and debug your program.

First thing to try would be to delete the `bin` and `obj` folders and try again. Files in these folders will get regenerated on the next build attempt.

If that doesn't work, can you please share the contents of your `Hello_world.csproj` file?